# AWS subdomains issues

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-web-services, cloudflare

**Hi guys!**

I've tried to create a couple of subdomains for my website.
I created virtual hosts in the apache configuration and I added the records to the Amazon Route53. But now, it's working sometimes and sometimes it's not working..

Let's say that I checked the subdomain around 2 hours ago and it did work, and now when I'm trying again it's not working, the browser throws me an error: Oops! Google Chrome could not find xyz.xyz.com

The records in the Route53 are the Elastic IP of the instance.
Now, because of security reasons and cache I'm using cloudflare services, I added all the needed records for the domain and looks like it's okay, but is the cloudflare could do problems with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without posting your dns subdomain names we cant resolve them to see what going on, but it you are experiencing resolutins sometimes and sometimes not, it may by a dns caching issue, that will resolve itself in few hours at most.

It could also be misconfigured "NS" records.... make sure these, and whois authoritative nameservers, match up. this is important.

if the issue is sometimes you get one resoltion, and sometimes a different one, for the same fqdn, then you may have unintentional multiple A records associated with that same fqdn.

Comment: what i need to give you?

Comment: paste the actual domain/subdomain in question, so we can see how it is resolving on the internet..... or do yourself with tools like http://intodns.com/

Comment: thank you. I'm already fix it, the problem was with the cloudflare records. I've tried to fix there some DNS records and it's worked!